# Is there developer folder available in Mac 10.9?

Tags: ios7, osx-mavericks, xcode5.1

I want to clear derived Data from Xcode. So, I need to go to developer folder. But I have checked completely and i am unable to find. Is there developer folder available anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya Sure,

1. Open the `Finder`
2. Click `Go menu` and hold the `alt key`
3. Then you will see the `Library folder` in the options
4. Click `Library` and there you will find `Developer folder`

hope it will work.